# Jquery datatable aoData not working django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatables

I am trying to setup the initial data in the Datatable.
I have the object_list from the views:

```
 object_list=[{'username': u'Paul', 'phone_number': u'9910087044', 'user_group__name': '', 'manager_name': ' ', 'role': '', 'full_name': u'Paul Kashyap', 'email': u'paul_kshyp_2004@yahoo.co.in'},
     {'username': u'paul@teramera.co', 'phone_number': '', 'user_group__name': u'user_group', 'manager_name': u'Paul Kashyap', 'role': '', 'full_name': u'Nishant Teramera Kashyap Teramera', 'email': u'xsxs@dcs.com'}]
```

And

```
object_header_list=[{'mdata': 'username', 'sTitle': 'Username'}, {'mdata': 'phone_number', 'sTitle': 'Phone Number'}, {'mdata': 'user_group__name', 'sTitle': 'User Group  Name'}, {'mdata': 'manager_name', 'sTitle': 'Manager Name'}, {'mdata': 'role', 'sTitle': 'Role'}, {'mdata': 'full_name', 'sTitle': 'Full Name'}, {'mdata': 'email', 'sTitle': 'Email'}]
```

Both of which I am passing in HTML and parsing Json
Using `$.parseJSON` in jquery.

And Jquery is :

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
    {
        var table_headers = $.parseJSON('{{ object_list_headers|safe }}');
        var table_data    = $.parseJSON('{{ object_list|safe }}');
        console.log(table_data);
        console.log(table_headers);


        $('#UserTable').dataTable({
            "aoData":table_data,
            "aoColumns":  table_headers,
            "sPaginationType":"bs_full"
         });
```

The headers of the Table are coming well, but in the rows it is showing `No data available in table`.

Now i have no idea why data is not coming, I have tried using aaData, then it shows a alert

```
DataTables warning (table id = 'UserTable'): Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row 0
```

I dont know why the data is not showing up in the rows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `object_header_list` list should have the keys `mData` not `mdata`.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry i did not closed the question. I got the answer by looking closely the Javascript object that was passing.
I think javascript lack in giving the proper error.Its very annoying sometimes to work on Javascript stuffs.